# Is there a way to multiply a nullable with a compact operator, something like "?*"

Tags: dart, nullable

Is there a way to get a multiplication with a nullable using a compact syntax such as:

```dart
int? i;

final j = i ?* 2 ?? null;
```

Rater than:

```dart
final j = i == null ? null : i! * 2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
There is no null-aware syntax which extends to operators (other than `[]` and `[]=`).

You can introduce an extension method doing multiplication, like:

```dart
extension IntOps on int {
  int imul(int other) => this * other;
  int iadd(int other) => this + other;
  int isub(int other) => this - other;
  // etc.
}
```

and then you can do:

```dart
int? i;
final j = i?.imul(2);
```